# How to get root privileges in cocoa os x with swift?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, root

I'm searching some little example of code explains to how ask system about root privileges for all running time with swift

Comment: what are you trying to do with the root permissions? Run a `sudo` command? Shell script?

Comment: Apple has an Objective-C guide on the Authorization Services API here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/authorization_concepts/01introduction/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000995-CH204-TP1

Comment: @AaronGill-Braun Is it possible to run sudo command?